# Question about rational points on elliptics curves.

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-equations

I have the following question about this lemma,

[image]

Where $A,B\in\mathbb{F}$. I tried to prove that $\mbox{Norm}_{R/F}(\alpha-\beta\theta)=f^{hom}(\alpha,\beta))$, but I don't see, why this is correct. Any hint will be appreciated. Just to be certain, in this case $\mbox{Norm}_{R/\mathbb{F}}$ is the norm in the finite field and $\mbox{hom}$ is the homomorphism?

Thanks!

This is from Andrew Shallue's papers https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0139/0ce5986e93cc6ffa35050566760c96640c1a.pdf

Comment: If $f \in F[x] $ is monic irreducible separable with roots $\theta_j$ and $R = F[x]/(f)$ and $\alpha, \beta \in F$ then $Norm_{R/F}(\alpha-\theta_j \beta)  \overset{def}= \prod_{l=1}^{\deg(f)} (\alpha-\theta_l \beta) = \beta^{\deg(f)} f(\alpha/\beta)$. To show [this is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm#Formal_definition) also $\det(z \mapsto (\alpha-\theta_j \beta) z)$ you'd need some Galois theory. If $f = \prod_m f_m$ is not irreducible but doesn't have double roots then the same holds because $R \cong \prod_m F[x]/(f_m)$.